# Loop through website and extract all occurrences

Tags: loops, imacros

I'm trying to go with an iMacro through website and extract text and urls, **which are shown up in every occurrence of certain class**.

My iMacro looks like the following, but it doesn't work like I expect:

```
VERSION BUILD=7601105 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1

URL GOTO=http://www.example.com

SET !LOADCHECK YES

TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:spanclassA&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=R-1 TYPE=A ATTR=class:linkclassAA EXTRACT=HREF

TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:spanclassB&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=R-1 TYPE=A ATTR=class:linkclassBB EXTRACT=HREF

SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=+{{!NOW:ddmmyyyy}}.csv
```

It extracts only respective first occurrences: the export file contains only 4 values. But I need, and expected with `{{!LOOP}}`, that I get all occurrences on the page. How do I get them all?

I was trying even just this:

```
VERSION BUILD=7601105 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1

URL GOTO=http://www.example.com

SET !LOADCHECK YES

TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:spanclassA&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT

SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=+{{!NOW:ddmmyyyy}}.csv
```

but it takes only the first occurrence too.

Comment: If you play this macro in loop mode, such extraction must work correctly.

Comment: @Shugar do i understand correctly: should it load the page, scrape position one, then reload the page, scrape position two and so on, scraping only one position while one page load? Or should it load the page only once and then go through all positions one by one?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to load the web page only once and then to go through all positions one by one. Something like this:

```
SET myUrl http://www.example.com
SET url EVAL("({{!LOOP}} == 1) ? '{{myUrl}}' : 'javascript: undefined;';")
URL GOTO={{url}}

TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:spanclassA&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=+{{!NOW:ddmmyyyy}}.csv
```